# Use pymongo instance inside a function in a route

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

I have the following structure in my app.py file

```
app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/DATABASE"
 mongo = PyMongo(app)
 
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    input = request.get_json()
    myFunction(input) # Needs access to multiple collections of MongoDB

    return input


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=4000)
```

and functions.py file

```
def function1(input):
    ... # Uses Mongo Collection 1

def function2(input):
    ... # Access Mongo Collection 1

def function3(input):
    ... # Access Mongo Collection 2

def myFunction(input):
    function1(input)
    function2(input)
    function3(input)
```

I want to import myFunction() from a functions.py file but I can't find a way of passing the mongo instance to it.

Comment: Add the mongo instance as the function parameter for myFunction and pass the parameter while calling.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but I was thinking of a more "elegant" solution where mongo instance is global or something..